# How to execute a terminal script in Linux from a php file

Tags: php, linux, terminal, raspberry-pi

So I am sorry if I mess up the names a little. I am still pretty new to linux.

I setup a headless raspberry pi webserver. I installed TightVNC Server on it so I could remote in but for the life of me I can't get the damn server to start when my pi reboots.

My work around to this is to have a php script that I can call from the web that executes a terminal script that starts TightVNC. I don't know if it's called terminal script or not but in windows its called a bat file.

Do php files have this permission? If so what is the php command to execute this file?

Comment: Why don't you modify your linux start up parameters to run a `.sh` script to run the service for TightVNC?

Comment: @DarylGill because I have no clue how to do that. That was the reason for the question. Can you post this example as an answer?

Comment: As someone with nearly 2k reputation, you should know how questions work here... Consult google, try out your research then post here problems or hire a developer, i'm not going to construct an entire script for you

Comment: @DarylGill I did consult google. I came across two separate examples that I attempted. neither of them worked. That was why I came to SO to ask the community. I was hoping that people would be mature about the question and realize there wasn't any code I could post. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Its amazing that a question that I should have consulted google for is so popular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a shell command with PHP, use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php). It will run as the web user (say, www for Apache), so that user will need to have appropriate permissions. You could, of course, use sudo to get around that - but that is extremely insecure and a very, very bad idea.

So if you had, e.g. a shell script called shellscript.sh sitting on yoru server, and you've written it to do whatever you need it to do, you could run it in php with:

```
shell_exec('sh path/to/shellscript.sh')
```

However - I'm not sure I correctly understand what you're trying to do, but it seems to me this is a hacky, very inefficient way to go about things, and it's very likely there is a much smoother solution. Even so, good luck.